# How do I troubleshoot a Windows Update Error "Installer encountered an error: 0x8000fff Catastrophic Failure"

Tags: c#, setup-project, windows-update

I have a batch script that uninstalls a Windows Update.

```
@echo off
REM uninstall windows update
wusa /uninstall /kb:2592687 /quiet /norestart
```

When I run it from the command line it executes just fine.
But when I call it from a C# installer class

```
protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);
        Process proc = new Process();
        try
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"path\to\bat";
            proc.Start();

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

I get the error message in the title and the update doesn't uninstall.
I've run the setup as an admin and got the same error and I've googled it and found almost nothing helpful. What kind of steps should I take to figure out what is causing the error and fix it?

UPDATE:
After some more poking around I got to the Event Viewer and got a less vague error

```
Windows update  could not be uninstalled because of error 2147549183
```

Which led to a page that talks about 64bit vs 32 bit. And changing my code to what they suggested

```
Process proc = new Process();
        try
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c path\to\kbunins.bat";
            proc.Start();
            MessageBox.Show("Success.");
        }
```

Now doesn't even add a new event in the log and the KB is still installed.